# How do I query sql for non intersect data and the latest intersect data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that is a collection entries of logged on patient.

```
   patient, room,   startDate,       endDate
   -------------------------------------------
    0056    001     2012-05-30      2012-05-30 
    0056    001     2013-08-01      2014-09-01 
    0056    001     2013-08-01      2014-09-02
    0056    001     2014-08-01      2014-09-03 
    0056    001     2015-08-01      2016-01-01 
    0056    112     2016-03-01      2017-02-28 
    0005    001     2013-05-01      2014-04-30 
    0005    006     2013-05-01      2015-03-27
```

How do I create a query that would give me the non-intersect dateStart and dateEnd, and distinct latest date of patient which intersect?

The result should be:

```
   patient, room,   startDate,       endDate
   -------------------------------------------
    0056    001     2012-05-30      2012-05-30 
    0056    001     2013-08-01      2014-09-03 
    0056    001     2015-08-01      2016-01-01 
    0056    112     2016-03-01      2017-02-28 
    0005    001     2013-05-01      2014-04-30 
    0005    006     2013-05-01      2015-03-27
```

`Row 1` is selected since it's `startDate` and `endDate` is not between `row 2,3,and 4`. 
However, `Row 2`, `row 3`, and `row 4` are intersect. So, it just get the latest endDate

The query I've tried:

```
SELECT 
    patient
    ,room
    ,startDate
    ,endDate
FROM T_PATIENT 
GROUP BY 
    patient
    ,room
    ,startDate
    ,endDate
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? MySQL, SQL Server, other?

Comment: SQL Server @GiorgosBetsos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `OUTER APPLY` to sort out overlapping records and determine the corresponding 'start - end' overlapping period:

```
SELECT patient, room, startDate, endDate, min_start, max_end
FROM T_PATIENT AS t1  
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT MIN(startDate) AS min_start, MAX(endDate) AS max_end
   FROM T_PATIENT AS t2
   WHERE t1.patient = t2.patient AND 
         t1.startDate <= t2.endDate AND 
         t1.endDate >= t2.startDate
) AS c
```

**Output:**

```
patient room  startDate   endDate     min_start   max_end
------------------------------------------------------------
56      1     2012-05-30  2012-05-30  2012-05-30  2012-05-30 
56      1     2013-08-01  2014-09-01  2013-08-01  2014-09-03 
56      1     2013-08-01  2014-09-02  2013-08-01  2014-09-03 
56      1     2014-08-01  2014-09-03  2013-08-01  2014-09-03 
56      1     2015-08-01  2016-01-01  2015-08-01  2016-01-01 
56      112   2016-03-01  2017-02-28  2016-03-01  2017-02-28 
5       1     2013-05-01  2014-04-30  2013-05-01  2015-03-27 
5       6     2013-05-01  2015-03-27  2013-05-01  2015-03-27
```

You can now apply grouping to the results above in order to consolidate overlapping records.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM T_PATIENT  T 
WHERE NOT EXISTS  (
SELECT * FROM T_PATIENT T1 WHERE 
( ( (T.STARTDATE  <= T1.STARTDATE   AND T.ENDDATE >=T1.STARTDATE) 
  OR (T .STARTDATE >= T1.ENDDATE    AND T.ENDDATE <=T1.ENDDATE ) 
  )  AND T.patient =T1.patient AND T.room=T1.room
  AND NOT(T.patient =T1.Patient 
  AND T.Room =T1.Room and T.STARTDATE =T1.STARTDATE 
  AND T.ENDDATE =T1.ENDDATE) ))
```